# What is the best for user restriction?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, content-management-system, web

Hello i want to make a site that will have a registration page a log-in page. After logging-in users will be able to fill a form and save it in their account.

I want as an administrator to control users so after their registration will be able to log-in after i approve them. and to be able to pause their log-in after a certain amount of time(in months).

What is the best way to do that?

Is it any good using a wordpress plug in for that and what plug-in will be that.

I know some PHP and SQL but don't have too much experience to building it fro scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this article  [Simple and Secure PHP Login Script](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Creating-a-Secure-PHP-Login-Script-59941/) since it has a very good security review here [Security Review: Creating a Secure PHP Login Script](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2011/08/security-review-creating-secure-php.html). Assuming that you have read the articles you can add a Boolean `verified` field to the `authentication` table set 0 by default. Then from the admin panel you can revise all non-verified users.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if I understand your goal completely, but it sounds like the [WordPress Membership Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/membership/) may be able to help you out.

Comment: Yes it's just like what i'm looking for but there is one more thing. i want users to be able to have an on line list or something, and i want every user to be able to control his own list only. They will fill their list using a form.

Comment: Is the list something that could be handled through the User's Profile?

Comment: no it will be the only page i wan't them to see a form they will fill the blanks and click save then the form wil be saved and the fields will be the rows of the list. each user will have his one and only list.

Comment: Again, I apologize if I'm not following correctly, but it seems like this could be done with custom profile fields.  When they sign up, they are redirected to their edit profile page, and you have X amount of custom fields.  Here's a tutorial on adding custom fields to user profiles: http://wpengineer.com/2173/custom-fields-wordpress-user-profile/

Comment: i want to make something like that http://css-tricks.com/app-from-scratch-1-design/ but i also want to be able to activate and pause users as an administrator. that's all